# Swift generic tree convert to int

Tags: swift, generics, tree

I'm trying to create a node to be used with trees, and this is the node class I created using generics.

```
class TreeNode<T: Comparable, Randomizable> {
var object: T
var left: TreeNode?
var right: TreeNode?

init(object: T, left: TreeNode?, right: TreeNode?) {
    self.object = object
    self.left = left
    self.right = right
}
}
```

Now, I have another function that will fill a tree with random integers.

```
class Tree<T: Comparable, Randomizable> {
var root: TreeNode<T, Randomizable>? = nil

func generateIntTree(depth: Int = 5, maxNumNodesPerLevel: Int = 2, minValue: Int = 0, maxValue: Int = 20) {
    root = TreeNode<Int, Int>.init(object: Int.random(in: minValue...maxValue), left: nil, right: nil)
}
```

The error message I am getting is Cannot assign value of type 'TreeNode' to type 'TreeNode<_, _>?'

Should I use Any instead? But I still want to keep my extensions.

Comment: You currently have two generic parameters in your class: one called `T` which needs to be `Comparable` and one called `Randomizable` with no constraints.  I'm assuming you want `TreeNode<T: Comparable & Randomizable>`

Comment: even still, `generateIntTree` can't exist under the `TreeNode` declaration as it currently is, because it's not generic. It hard-codes `T` as `Int`, which is only possible if this is a conditional extension on `TreeNode`: `extension TreeNode where T == Int`, which defeats the purpose of this being generic.

Comment: How would you solve this problem? I want to create a tree to be able to hold anything that conforms to Comparable and Randomizable. But I also want to have a function to create an instance of a tree with ints as its element.

Comment: `Randomizable` it is the same as `R`. It is just a generic type, it can be anything. It is pointless there

Comment: Show your `root` object declaration and where `generateIntTree` is declared

Comment: try `root = TreeNode<Int, Int>.init(object: Int.random(in: minValue...maxValue), left: nil, right: nil)`

Comment: or `root = TreeNode<Int, Any>.init(object: Int.random(in: minValue...maxValue), left: nil, right: nil)`

Comment: Edited my original post to show how I declare root within the Tree class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the error of `T: Comparable, Randomizable` and `T: Comparable & Randomizable`, you also have an issue with hard coding `Int.random(...)` in an assignment to `root` of type `TreeNode<T>?`. Such an assignment is only valid if `Int` and `T` are the same type, which isn't true in a unbounded generic context (e.g. the declaration of `Tree<T>`). It's only true in a conditional extension, `extension Tree where T == Int`

```
// Stubs to make it compile

public protocol Randomizable {}
extension Int: Randomizable {}

private class TreeNode<T: Comparable & Randomizable> {
    var object: T
    var left: TreeNode?
    var right: TreeNode?

    init(object: T, left: TreeNode?, right: TreeNode?) {
        self.object = object
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
    }
}

public class Tree<T: Comparable & Randomizable> {
    fileprivate var root: TreeNode<T>?

    fileprivate init(root: TreeNode<T>? = nil) { self.root = root }
}

extension Tree where T == Int {
    public func generateIntTree(
        depth: Int = 5,
        maxNumNodesPerLevel: Int = 2,
        minValue: Int = 0,
        maxValue: Int = 20
    ) -> Tree<Int> {
        return Tree(root:
            generateIntTree(
                depth: depth,
                maxNumNodesPerLevel: maxNumNodesPerLevel,
                minValue: minValue,
                maxValue: maxValue
            )
        )
    }

    private func generateIntTree(
        depth: Int = 5,
        maxNumNodesPerLevel: Int = 2,
        minValue: Int = 0,
        maxValue: Int = 20
    ) -> TreeNode<Int>? {
        if depth == 0 { return nil }
        let payload = Int.random(in: minValue...maxValue)

        return TreeNode(
            object: payload,
            left: generateIntTree(
                depth: depth - 1,
                minValue: minValue,
                maxValue: maxValue
            ),
            right: generateIntTree(
                depth: depth - 1,
                minValue: minValue,
                maxValue: maxValue
            )
        )
    }
}
```

Also, don't pass around `min`/`max` `Int` values like that. As you see, it's really clunky (always having to pass two separate things around), and it's error-prone (you can't easily accidentally assign `min` where `max` belongs, or vice versa). `Range<T>` exists. Use it. Look how much nicer it becomes:

```
extension Tree where T == Int {
    public func generateIntTree(
        depth: Int = 5,
        maxNumNodesPerLevel: Int = 2,
        valueRange: ClosedRange<Int> = 0...20
    ) -> Tree<Int> {
        return Tree(root:
            generateIntTree(
                depth: depth,
                maxNumNodesPerLevel: maxNumNodesPerLevel,
                valueRange: valueRange
            )
        )
    }

    private func generateIntTree(
        depth: Int = 5,
        maxNumNodesPerLevel: Int = 2,
        valueRange: ClosedRange<Int> = 0...20
    ) -> TreeNode<Int>? {
        if depth == 0 { return nil }
        let payload = Int.random(in: valueRange)

        return TreeNode(
            object: payload,
            left: generateIntTree(depth: depth - 1, valueRange: valueRange),
            right: generateIntTree(depth: depth - 1, valueRange: valueRange)
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I think this one takes the cake.

Comment: @Latcie I would also recommend you look into making use of the `Randomizable` protocol, whatever that is. Change your `generateIntTree` to  `generateRandomTree`, change the extension to `extension Tree where T: Randomizable {...}`and rather than hard-coding the type of random value, call the protocol methods of `Randomizable` to generate the payloads. As it is right now it's just an arbitrary excess constraint on your tree type. There's no reason why you couldn't have a tree of non-randomizable elements.